# Convertir Calendar a Date para almacenarlo en base de datos SQLite

Tags: java, mvc, sqlite, ftp

Necesito convertir un variable CALENDAR a DATE (para obtener fecha y hora) , para que luego de ello esa variable DATE se guarde en una tabla de SQLite que tiene tipo DATETIME.

Aclarado esto comencemos por mostrar la tabla SQLite llamada "archivo", la cual planeo contenga los datos de los documentos de un directorio alojado en un servidor FTP

[image: Tabla archivo]

Ahora, la tabla se llena leyendo el directorio FTP y sacando atributos de los archivos (usando métodos de las bibliotecas de commons.net.ftp*) aquí el codigo

```
public void cargarArchivos() {
    Connection con=null;
    FTPClient ftp=null;
    try {
        con=Conector.connect();
        ftp=Conector_FTP.cliente();
        FTPFile[] files = ftp.listFiles();
        for (FTPFile file : files) {

            if (file.isFile()) {
               String name = file.getName();
               long tamanio=file.getSize();
               Calendar fecha=file.getTimestamp();               
             PreparedStatement st= con.prepareStatement("insert into archivo (nombre,tamanio,fechamod) VALUES (?,?,?);");
                st.setString(1, name);
                st.setDouble(2, tamanio);
                st.setDate(3, fecha);
                st.execute();
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

El problema se presenta cuando quiero pasar la variable Calendar fecha y usarlo en un setDate para mandarlo a la base de datos como se ve aqui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente parsearlo y varias opciones que encontré por Internet y no puedo mandar la variable a la base de datos

Comment: ya intentaste con `setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(fecha.getTimeInMillis()))`?

Comment: @Sr1871 , ya ahora si deja agregar en la base de datos :D , pero me sale un numero largo , por ejemplo este 1393822800000 , que significa?

Comment: intenta con getTime() en lugar de getTimeInMillis()

Answer (score 0):

Como  pone en esta respuesta de stackOverFlown  (versión inglesa), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date, lo que tienes que hacer es convertir la clase java.util.Date a java.sql.Date, para hacer eso, tienes que hacer algo como esto:

```
   java.util.Date fechaActual= new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
   java.sql.Date fechaSql= java.sql.Date.valueOf(fechaActual.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
```

Una vez tengas un java.sql.Date podras poner en tu st.toDate.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me permite grabar en la base de datos, pero por ejemplo la fecha de creacion del documento es 2/3/14 19:00:00 , y la base de datos registra la fecha como  1393822800000 , hay algún error ? , porque luego necesitare mostrar ese valor en web

Comment: ¿Como estas sacando ese valor de la base de datos ?.  No es el campo tipo fecha ?. Si es fecha no entiendo que tipo de fecha es, a no ser que sea en milisegundos, pero ya es un problema de como estas cogiendo el dato. SQLLite, ya sabes que no soporta formato tipo fecha, como tal.